# Is it possible to use Lucene of Solr for image retrieval?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am searching for a retrieval server right now for my image retrieval project. As I see from the Internet, Lucene and Solr are particularized for textual seraching but do you think is it possible and reasonable to convey them for image retrieval.

You might suggest a image specific tool like LIRE but it has predefined featreu extraction algorithms and not very flexible for new features. Basically, all I need to index my image features from my extraction pipeline (written in Python) with a server like Lucene or Solr and perform some retrieval tasks based on Euclidean distance on indexed features.

Any suggestion or pointer to any reference would be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Have a read in this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773189/using-solr-to-calculate-similarity-bitcount-between-two-ulongs They generate hashes of images.

Comment: Do you need to store images in solr? Or do you just want to search the images based on some feature?

Comment: I'll just search these images based on features. I do not need to keep images in solr if not possible

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post , you could store the features as keyword fields in Lucene or ES (solr has a strict schema definition and i don't think it would fit your needs very well as the feature matrix is usually sparsely populated in my understanding), and have a unique ID field from the image hash. Then you can just search for feature values ( feature1:value1 AND feature2:value2) and see what matches the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to work with Euclidean distances, you'll want to look into using [the Spatial Features of Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search). This will allow you to index your values as coordinates, then perform indexed lookups from other points and sort by their Euclidean distances.

You might also want [to look at the dist and sqedist functions](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#dist).